# Spark Hive - UDFArgumentTypeException with window function?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

I have the following df:

```
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+                                 
|increment_id|base_subtotal_incl_tax|          eventdate|                                 
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2015-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2015-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2015-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2015-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|             1570.0000|2015-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

I'm trying to run a window function as:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id")).orderBy(df.col("eventdate").desc());
df.select(df.col("*"),rank().over(window).alias("rank")) //error for this line
         .filter("rank <= 2")
         .show();
```

What I want to get is the last two entries (last as for the latest date, but since it's ordered by descending, the first two rows) for each user:

```
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+                                 
|increment_id|base_subtotal_incl_tax|          eventdate|                                 
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|   
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                 
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|                                     
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+
```

but I get this:

```
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+----+
|increment_id|base_subtotal_incl_tax|          eventdate|rank|                            
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+----+                            
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
|        5555|            14470.0000|2014-07-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
|        1086|            14470.0000|2016-06-14 09:54:12|   1|                            
+------------+----------------------+-------------------+----+
```

What am I missing?

[OLD] - originally, I had an error, this is solved now:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id"));
df.select(df.col("*"),rank().over(window).alias("rank")) //error for this line
         .filter("rank <= 2")
         .show();
```

This, however returns an error `Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDFArgumentTypeException: One or
 more arguments are expected.` for the line marked above with a comment. What am I missing? What does this error mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rank` window function requires a window with `orderBy`, clause for example:

```
WindowSpec window = Window.partitionBy(df.col("id")).orderBy(df.col("payment"));
```

Without an order it is simply meaningless, hence the error.

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept your answer, but updated my question. If you can help me with this, too, I'd be very thankful.